# load dynamic dropdownlist with json function but not working on ie 11

Tags: json, internet-explorer, ddl

i have a function that works well in firefox and chrome But no in ie11, the problem is that the dropdown lists are showing empty and not data are coming to the select boxes.. :( please some help guys cause i m trying for ages to solve this with no lack..

my function is the following

```
function loadDynamicDdl(ajaxUrl , ddlId) {     
  $.ajax({
    dataType:'json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: ajaxUrl,
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    success:function (response) {
        var ddl = $('#' + ddlId);
        ddl.empty();           
        var opts = response.Options;         
        $.each(opts, function(i, item) {
           ddl.append($("<option />").val(item.Value).text(item.DisplayText));             
         });
      },
    error:function (jqXHR, exception) {
        //alert("There was an error loading dropdownlist.");
    }
});
```

}

why omg is not working in internet explorer 11  ??? why,,, please guys i m about to break my head on the keyboard.. thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   function loadDynamicDdl(ajaxUrl , ddlId) {
   $.ajax({
    dataType:'json',
      type: 'GET',
      url: ajaxUrl,
      cache:true,
      // contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
      async:false,
      success:function (response) {

          if (response.Result == 'ERROR') { 
              $('#system-message-container').html('<h2 style="color:red;">' + response.Message + '</h2>');
          $('#maincontent-container').hide();
         }

      var ddl = $('#' + ddlId);
      ddl.empty();            
       var opts = response.Options;
       //Not working when we have duplicates in json
      //      $.each(opts, function(i, item) {
      // ddl.append($("<option />").val(item.Value).text(item.DisplayText));
     //    });         
     //Start checking for duplicates numbers in the Value field and DisplayTexts in json and push the uniques
    var finalResult = [];
    var Values =[];
    var DisplayTexts = [];
    $.each(opts, function (i, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.DisplayText, DisplayTexts) == -1 && ($.inArray(value.Value, Values) == -1)) {    // it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match
    Values.push(value.Value);
    DisplayTexts.push(value.DisplayText);
    finalResult.push(value);      
   ddl.append($("<option />").val(value.Value).text(value.DisplayText));
   }
  });
  },   
  error:function (jqXHR, exception) {
        //alert("There was an error loading dropdownlist.");
      }
   });
   }
```